# How to get tag contents (including all text and elements)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a html snippet (no other parent elements):

```
html = '<div id="mydiv"><p>Hello</p><p>Goodbye</p>[...]</div>'
```

How do I extract all the tags and text (which may be variable) within the `div`, but not the div tag itself? I.e.L

```
target_str = '<p>Hello</p><p>Goodbye</p>[...]'
```

I have tried:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'html.parser')
mydiv = soup.find(id='mydiv')
print(mydiv)
>>> '<div id="mydiv"><p>Hello</p><p>Goodbye</p>[...]</div>'

mydiv.unwrap()
print(mydiv)
>>> '<div id="mydiv"></div>'
```

How do I get just the contents of the tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div id="mydiv"><p>Hello</p><p>Goodbye</p>[...]</div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print("".join(map(str, soup.select_one("#mydiv").contents)))
```

Prints:

```
<p>Hello</p><p>Goodbye</p>[...]
```